# Determine if a mousedown will trigger contextmenu in JS

Tags: javascript, event-handling, contextmenu

I want to handle `mousedown` events, but not those which will trigger immediately later a `contextmenu` event.

As `mousedown` events are dispatched before `contextmenu` events, I can't "flag" the event somehow (e.g. by recording its `timeStamp`) in the `contextmenu` handler.

Of course, I can check `event.ctrlKey` in the `mousedown` handler, but that misses some other ways a context menu can be triggered (and, I assume, platform specific details). So how can I determine for sure if a `contextmenu` will follow?

Comment: To be sure -- Your question on how to determine, whether a `mousedown` event is succeeded by a `contextmenu` event, is equivalent to the problem on how to determine whether a `contextmenu` was preceded by `mousedown`, right?

Comment: @Krokomot Not quite, because there is also stuff I want to do in `mousedown` if no `contextmenu` will follow. Actually, this is my main concern: find a way to not do my normal stuff in `mousedown` if this is actually a context menu trigger.

Comment: @Jean-PhilippePellet What is it that you (sometimes) want to do in your mousedown handler? Any chance to delay that a bit?

Comment: @Bergi it starts either moving items or selecting them. I want to avoid delaying anything if I can.

Comment: @Jean-PhilippePellet You mean like a drag action? That should only be done with the primary button.

Comment: @Bergi Alright, sounds like checking the button is a decent solution after all, then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, that there are different ways to trigger the [`contextmenu`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/contextmenu_event) event, however the issue, as you describe it, melts down to the case "[***`mousedown`***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousedown_event) and `contextmenu`".

In general a `contextmenu` event will follow a `mousedown` when the secondary mouse button was pressed. A special case for Mac we'll discuss later.

---

**NB:** The secondary button is usually the right one, when not configured otherwise. Left-handers e.g. will prefer the left mouse button. However, that's unimportant here, so lets stick to the configuration-independent term *secondary button*.

---

Now, you can check in your `mousedown` handler which button has been pressed, querying the [`button property`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/button) of a [MouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent) object. The secondary button is represented by the number `2`. So if `MouseEvent.button == 2` in the `mousedown` handler, than don't execute that stuff you want to skip in case a `contextmenu` event was triggered.

Further, on [Apple devices](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/context-menus) one can also employ the primary -- i.e. usually but not necessarily left -- mouse button while pressing the Control key. So the complete check in the `mousedown` handler on a `MouseEvent` object `e` is:

```
e.button == 2 || (e.button == 0 && e.ctrlKey)
```

If this is `true`, a `contextmenu` event will (right-click) or may (left-click + ctrl) follow. On Windows and Linux a left-click with Control will be misinterpreted as a `click` event after `mouseup`. Either hope that no ones come to that idea on Windows or Linux, or catch that case.

This should cover all *mouse-related* triggers for `contextmenu` on common operating systems, i.e. Windows, Linux and Mac.

---

As [aarvinr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21392777/aarvinr) pointed out in his comment, one can also employ the [`MouseEvent.buttons`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/buttons) property for this purpose.

Comment: You can also use [`MouseEvent.buttons`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/buttons) to check if any other keys are held down during the click - similar to `MouseEvent.ctrlKey`, but more versatile for other platforms.

Comment: True. Added it to the answer. Thx.

Comment: OK, that works to some extent and it's what I'm doing now. But still it's some reverse engineering, and it may yield false positive or false negatives for some system settings or platforms, I assume...

Comment: Updated to cover Mac.

Comment: In short -- The "context menu via mouse" scenario consists of two cases. "Secondary mouse button down" on Windows/Linux/Max and "Primary mouse button down plus Control" on Mac only. Latter throws a false positive on Windows/Linux as it'll be interpreted as `click` event after `mouseup`. That's the only edge case you'll have to catch. Remember -- you can not be responsible for any exotic platfom or system setting on this world. BTW -- left-handers are not affected, as its a primary/secondary-button thing and ***not*** a left/right button one.

Comment: And be assured -- that's no reverse engineering at all but a common approach.